# A group of order $n$ is cyclic if and only if it contains an element of order $n$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I have a question. Unfortunately, I am not THAT algebra specialist, but I hope someone could help me.

My question is:

> Does the following statement hold: "A group of order $n$ is cyclic if and only if it has an element of order $n$."

Well, it's clear that if a group $G$ is cyclic of order $n$, then the order of the generator $g$ has to be $n$, since

$$\vert g\vert=\vert\langle g\rangle\vert =\vert G\vert =n.$$

My problem is that I know what holds if a group is cyclic, but not what has to hold that a group becomes cyclic.

Comment: A group is cyclic if it is finite and generated by one element by definition. If a finite group G has an element of order $\vert G \vert$, then this element is a generator of $G$.

Comment: Yeah, this is borderline the definition of cyclic.

Comment: But $$(\Bbb Z, +)\cong \langle z\mid \varnothing \rangle$$ is cyclic but infinite, @AlexL.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an element $a$ of order $n$, it means that the subgroup $A\leq G$ generated by $a$ is of order $n$. As the order of $G$ is also $n$, you get $A = G$, i.e. $G$ is cyclic and generated for example by $a$.